# Third Person Car Dashboard Appeared

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I've been playing a lot of GTAO, and a couple of weeks ago I somehow managed to get the dials for my cars dashboard (Speedometer, fuel gauge etc.) to display in the top left of the screen in **third person** mode.

I know the dials are visible and working in first person mode, but they appeared in third person as black outlines. It definitely wasn't a bug from the first person dials, as they were styled differently from first person, and there were a lot of extra dials when I entered a helicopter.

I've got no idea what I pressed, or how I got it to go away again. Anyone seen this or know how to enable it?

Comment: reddit says its a glitch

Comment: Do you have a link to the reddit post?
That's disappointing, I liked having the dashboard dials.

Comment: I can look if I find it again....

here it was linked in reddit and it was related to your Question (if you are steve jose)

http://imgur.com/a/Yo5JE

http://www.reddit.com/r/GTAV/related/33ee8s/gtao_pc_car_dashboard_in_third_person/

http://www.reddit.com/r/GrandTheftAutoV_PC/comments/33glzg/weird_glitch_car_dashboard_ui_overlayed_on_hud/?

Comment: Ah, excellent! Thanks for your help. Hope someone notices and can work out how to force it on.

Comment: If modding wasn'T "illegal" there would be an solution soon. :-)   but at least it prevents cheating!